# How I obtain the differential equations of this LC connections

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I have this LC connections with three nodes vc1,vl2,vc3 and this notes equations.

$$C_{{1}}{\frac {d}{dt}}v_{{{\it c1}}} \left( t \right) -{\frac {\int \!
v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) {dt}}{L_{{2}}}}
=0\\
{\frac {\int \!v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) {dt}}{L_{{2}}}}+{\frac 
{\int \!v_{{{\it c3}}} \left( t \right) -v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t
 \right) {dt}}{L_{{4}}}}+{\frac {\int \!v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t
 \right) {dt}}{L_{{3}}}}
=0\\
C_{{5}}{\frac {d}{dt}}v_{{{\it c3}}} \left( t \right) -{\frac {\int \!
v_{{{\it c3}}} \left( t \right) -v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) {dt}}
{L_{{4}}}}
=0$$

differentiating I obtain :

$$C_{{1}}{\frac {d^{2}}{d{t}^{2}}}v_{{{\it c1}}} \left( t \right) -{
\frac {v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) }{L_{{2}}}}
=0\\
{\frac {v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) }{L_{{2}}}}+{\frac {v_{{{\it 
c3}}} \left( t \right) -v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) }{L_{{4}}}}+{
\frac {v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t \right) }{L_{{3}}}}
=0\\
C_{{5}}{\frac {d^{2}}{d{t}^{2}}}v_{{{\it c3}}} \left( t \right) -{
\frac {v_{{{\it c3}}} \left( t \right) -v_{{{\it l2}}} \left( t
 \right) }{L_{{4}}}}
=0$$

those equations are two differential equations and one algebraic equation.

I am not sure if this is the right  way to obtain the equations ??

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I didn't check the math explicitly but no issues with differentiating to get rid of integrals in an equation so that you end up with only derivatives.

Comment: @Andyaka First I just want to know is my equations correct?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No, it doesn't look fine, at all. I'm flummoxed that it does to you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to use your node names -- too confusing to me. Instead, they are \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$, left to right, then KCL provides (out-flowing currents on left, in-flowing currents on right):

$$\begin{align*}
C_1\frac{\text{d}\,V_1}{\text{d}t} + \frac1{L_2}\int V_1\:\text{d}t&=\frac1{L_2}\int V_2\:\text{d}t\\\\
\frac1{L_2}\int V_2\:\text{d}t+\frac1{L_3}\int V_2\:\text{d}t+\frac1{L_4}\int V_2\:\text{d}t &= \frac1{L_2}\int V_1\:\text{d}t+\frac1{L_4}\int V_3\:\text{d}t\\\\
C_5\frac{\text{d}\,V_3}{\text{d}t} +\frac1{L_4}\int V_3\:\text{d}t&=\frac1{L_4}\int V_2\:\text{d}t
\end{align*}$$

Re-arranged (into the sign-heavy, which-way-is-which approach that I think leads all too often into making mistakes, which is why I ***never*** use it anymore):

$$\begin{align*}
C_1\frac{\text{d}\,V_1}{\text{d}t} + \frac1{L_2}\int \left(V_1-V_2\right)\:\text{d}t&=0\:\text{A}\\\\
\frac1{L_2}\int \left(V_2-V_1\right)\:\text{d}t+\frac1{L_3}\int V_2\:\text{d}t+\frac1{L_4}\int \left(V_2-V_3\right)\:\text{d}t &= 0\:\text{A}\\\\
C_5\frac{\text{d}\,V_3}{\text{d}t} +\frac1{L_4}\int \left(V_3-V_2\right)\:\text{d}t&=0\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Taking the derivative with respect to time, leaves:

$$\begin{align*}
C_1\frac{\text{d}^2\,V_1}{\text{d}t^2} + \frac{V_1-V_2}{L_2}&=0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}\\\\
\frac{V_2-V_1}{L_2}+\frac{V_2}{L_3}+\frac{V_2-V_3}{L_4} &= 0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}\\\\
C_5\frac{\text{d}^2\,V_3}{\text{d}t^2} +\frac{V_3-V_2}{L_4}&=0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}
\end{align*}$$

You messed up on two of the three equations.

Non-trivial initial conditions will be needed for any non-trivial solution.

Comment: I try to find the analogy between Newton equations of motion and the electrical equations , so i realized that the voltages are the deflections, the spring constant is 1/L, the mass is C1 and C5 …

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have an algebraic equation is that it reflects the conservation of current -- the sum of currents arriving at node C2 is 0.

Comment: Why are the equations not symmetrical to the nodes vc1 and vc3 ?

Comment: because your 1st equation is incorrect -- the integral should be vl2-vc1, not just vl2. It would then be similar to your 3rd eq.

Comment: I see thank  you,  and also the algebraic equation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I will use the analogy between the Newton equations of motion and the electrical circle

**Newton**

$$m_i\,\ddot x_i=\sum F_i\tag 1$$

where

$$m_i\mapsto C_i\\
x_i\mapsto v_i$$

the forces are "spring forces"

$$F_1=k_1\,\Delta x\mapsto \frac{1}{L_2}(v_2-v_1)\\
F_2=\frac{1}{L_4}(v_2-v_3)\\
F_3=\frac{1}{L_3}(v_2)$$

thus:  equation (1)

$$C_1\ddot v_1=\frac{1}{L_2}(v_2-v_1)\\
C_5\ddot v_3=\frac{1}{L_2}(v_2-v_3)\\
-F_1-F_2+F_3=0\\
-\frac{1}{L_2}(v_2-v_1)-\frac{1}{L_2}(v_2-v_3)+\frac{1}{L_3}(v_2)=0$$

notice that  the "spring forces" must be is attractive force , so you can choose the correct sign.